# Need shipping help for EE Exp:resso Store

Tags: expresso-store

To keep a long story short. I'm running EE2.5.5 CMS and Exp:resso Store for the e-commerce bit.

My client sells a few items from his website, but has a warehouse do the shipping for him and they bill him once a month.

I want to use the UPS Shipping plugin that comes with Store, however I cannot get the Access Key, Username, Password required to calculate shipment costs... because that info does not belong to my client, it belongs to the warehouse who uses that same account to ship a variety of packages for other customers such as my client. When contacted, they mentioned something about a Generic UPS quoting account. is there such a thing? If not, how would you recommend me getting around this issue?

The original idea was to use the Default Shipping Plugin, but there's just too many variations for the client to keep track of and not lose money on when shipping.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be fine creating your own account with UPS and using that as the API that is used only gets the live rates and does not actually create a shipping ticket in UPS so your account shouldn't be charged anything.

Comment: Yea seems to be working well. I'm only seeing issues with International shipments. I get an error... The requested service is invalid from the selected origin.

Comment: Have you created International Shipping Methods?

Comment: Yes. I'm assuming it's similar to the zip/state issue I had. But even if i change the country it still stays at 0.00 and when i get back to the cart that's the error i see.

Comment: Did you ever get the usps international shipping to work? If so how ? Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to use UPS or USPS?

Answer (score 2):

Sure. Just call UPS and ask to set up an account. They will need a credit card, but as Justin mentioned Store doesn't request any shipments, so unless you do there won't be any charges.

This is what we did to develop the shipping integration for Store, so I know it's possible :) The UPS site and processes are a bit of a nightmare, but once you figure that out it's all downhill. If you're stuck, it's usually easier to call them rather than fighting with their website.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Adrian! We're in exactly the same situation in that we're working with a company who uses a local fulfillment center / warehouse with its own UPS account. So I did exactly as you describe.

I had to go through 3 or 4 "call levels" before I got to "specialty products" but I created a free account and successfully requested an API access key and I didn't have to use a credit card, either. Incidentally, the direct line as of 18 June 2013 for this UPS department in the US is 1 800 247 9035.

As for the Store settings, I added the username, password, and API access key into the UPS plugin. Is there anything else I need to do? About to begin testing.

Thanks! Keep up the work on a great software product -- Exp:resso Store is by far the best I've ever developed with.

Comment: Quick note -- with a bit of tweaking and testing, got the UPS shipping plugin to work like a charm. Confirmed that the a credit card is not necessary to get the API key.